# A.I. of crochet patterns- counting stitches and rows

Tags: algorithm, model, artificial-intelligence

I'm trying to create an AI model that will count stitches and rows in crochet pictures. I am not exactly sure how to approach this problem so I would like to get reccomendations of how and where to start. I dont have a lot of knowledge about AIs but am willing to learn. I want to code this AI using pycharm.

I did research and realised there is no already made data I can use or any models like this that work. So does this mean I need to manually create files of crochet pictures and where each stitch is located?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know much about AI so I won't answer, but I wonder if you could just use frequency analysis for this? i.e. the strongest frequency in the image in each direction would correspond to the period of the repeating stitch pattern. Maybe convert to greyscale and subtract a blurred version of the image first to reduce/remove the differences in color between stitches? You could possibly use this information in conjunction with an AI approach.